# How to bind properly to a service property in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, object-literal

I have a factory where I have a couple of predefined partners (it could be anything else, I thought it's an example that's easy to understand). On run time, we select the current partner (based on some logic I omitted here).

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('PartnersService', function ($location, $log) {

  var partners = {
    firstPartner: {
      name: 'Default Partner',
      id: 1 // just an extra property as example 
    },
    secondPartner: {
      name: 'Other Partner',
      id: 2
    }
  };

  // set default value
  var partner = partners.firstPartner;

  var initPartner = function () {
    // based on some logic (omitted), select partner
    partner = partners.secondPartner;
    $log.log("initPartner should have changed partner to " +  partner.name);
  };

  return {
    initPartner: initPartner,
    partners: partners,
    partner: partner,
  };
});
```

Then, I would like to access the partner as `PartnersService.partner` and see as it changes, e.g. from a controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController',
  function ($scope, $log, PartnersService) {
    // PartnersService.partner is the default partner (firstPartner)
    PartnersService.initPartner();
    // After initPartner, PartnersService.partner is still
    // the default, but I expected it to change
});
```

**I found some workarounds (in my opinion... *are they workarounds?*), but it feels unnatural for me, so I'd like to ask if there's a better way.**

**See my full, working example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kifixeseqe/edit?html,js,console,output). I apologize if you find the example a bit lengthy, but I wanted to make sure Stack Overflow users understand my concerns and can point out if something is wrong with the way I think.**

Workaround 1 (getter?):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $log, PartnersService) {
  PartnersService.initPartner();
  var partner = PartnersService.getPartner();
  $log.log('I could use a getter: ' + partner.name);
});

angular.module('myApp').factory('PartnersService', function ($location, $log) {

  var getPartner = function () {
    return partner;
  };

  return {
    getPartner: getPartner,
    // ...
  };
});
```

Workaround 2 (nest in an object literal):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $log, PartnersService) {
  PartnersService.initPartner();
  $log.log('or nest the partner in an extra object literal: '
     + PartnersService.extraObjectLiteral.partner.name);
});

angular.module('myApp').factory('PartnersService', function ($location, $log) {
  var partners = { /*...*/ }
  var extraObjectLiteral = {
    partner: partners.firstPartner
  };

  var initPartner = function () {
    // based on some logic (omitted), select partner
    extraObjectLiteral.partner = partners.secondPartner;
  };

  return {
    extraObjectLiteral: extraObjectLiteral,
    //...
  };
});
```

Comment: You want to change a **var** inside a factory service and you want changes to that var to appear magically in the model view **without** doing a fetch from the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
this.partner = partners.secondPartner;
```

in your initPartner method. That will solve it.

What you're really doing when you do

```
  var partners = { ... }
  var partner = partners.firstPartner;
```

is, you're creating local objects in the class, but they are not exposed members of the class. And with the

```
  return {
    initPartner: initPartner,
    partners: partners,
    partner: partner
  };
```

you create members of the class, and copy the values of the local variables to the class' members. In your initPartner method, you change the local object, but the class' object remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the approach of using getters and setters as this follows the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern) which is really preferred for maintaining cleaner, more readable and understandable code.

Factory code is as follows.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').
        factory('PartnersService', PartnersService);

    function PartnersService($location, $log) {
        var partners = {
            firstPartner: {
                name: 'Default Partner',
                id: 1 // just an extra property as example 
            },
            secondPartner: {
                name: 'Other Partner',
                id: 2
            }
        };
        var partner;

        //Set default value
        setDefaultPartner();

        var service = {
            getPartner: getPartner,
            setPartner: setPartner
        };
        return service;

        /*** Function Declarations ***/

        /* Accessible Functions */

        function getPartner() {
            return partner;
        }

        function setPartner() {
            var selectedPartner = initPartner();

            return selectedPartner;
        }

        /* Private Functions */

        function initPartner() {
            /*
             * Some (omitted) logic to select partner
             */

             partner = partners.secondPartner;
             $log.log("initPartner should have changed partner to " +  partner.name);

             return partner;
        }

        function setDefaultPartner() {
            partner = partners.firstPartner;
        }
    }
})();
```

Notice that the only public/accessible members left are the `getPartner` and `setPartner` (which calls `initPartner`) functions.

The controller would be the following.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').
        controller('myController', myController);

    function myController($scope, $log, PartnersService) {
        $scope.partner = PartnersService.getPartner();
        $log.log("should be default partner: " + $scope.partner.name);

        $scope.partner = PartnersService.setPartner();
        $log.log("After setPartner which calls initPartner, the current partner is now the " + $scope.partner.name);
    }
})();
```

Modifying your [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wuwagipake/1/edit?html,js,console,output), the following is the resulting console log.

```
"should be default partner: Default Partner"
"initPartner should have changed partner to Other Partner"
"After setPartner which calls initPartner, the current partner is now the Other Partner"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing anything obvious. Both of your workarounds seem ok to me, except that in the latter case I would probably use the following structure:

```
var partners = { ... };

var initPartner = function () {
    retObj.partner = partners.secondPartner;
};

var retObj = {
    initPartner: initPartner,
    partners: partners,
    partner: partners.firstPartner
};   

return retObj;
```